# Does RocksDB State store share across consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need to check and ignore the message if it has been processed before, what I have in mind is using the Kakfa State store to save the key in there and check to ignore message with the same key in the future.

I use the code below from Apache document, but when I start two consumers at once on my local machine, those with the same key can be executed twice if they got consumed by different consumer, so I think it won't share across the consumer.

```
StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, Long>> countStoreSupplier =
  Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
    Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("persistent-counts"),
    Serdes.String(),
    Serdes.Long());
KeyValueStore<String, Long> countStore = countStoreSupplier.build();
```

Is there any suggestion to make this state store global for all consumer?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Processor API in order to get a Statestore handle, and then use Interactive Queries to lookup from external store instances (which could be one per host/partition) in a distributed application.

1. If you look at the word count example in the docs - https://kafka.apache.org/35/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#connecting-processors-and-state-stores

   When you see a matching key, then you can choose not to modify the store with a new value
2. Then, you need a way to [query state of the whole app](https://kafka.apache.org/35/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#querying-remote-state-stores-for-the-entire-app) since each store is only one instance

You can also try using aggregate/reduce DSL functions, then chose to ignore any new keys